# What's the pattern to manipulate data in Observables (angular2)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs

suppose we have this service

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService {  

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    getCars() { 
        return this.http.get('someurl')
                .map(res => <Car[]> res.json())               
                .catch(this.handleError);  
    }   
}
```

and we subscribe to this in another component. If Car looks like this:

```
class Car{
   Color:string;
   Timestamp:any; //this comes as a string in JSON but I want it to be of type Date object
}
```

and we want to have some logic, ie change date:string to date type, where should this be done?

in a service? and how?
in a class itself? will .map() hit the constructor of Car class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this process either:

- in a `map` operator that leverages the `map` method of arrays

  ```
  return this.http.get('someurl')
          .map(res => <Car[]> res.json())
          .map(data => {
            data.map((d) => {
              var date = (...)
              return new Car(color, date);
            });
            return data;
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
  ```
- in the constructor of the `Car` class

  ```
  return this.http.get('someurl')
          .map(res => <Car[]> res.json())
          .map(data => {
            data.map((d) => {
              return new Car(color, timestampAsString);
            });
            return data;
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
  ```